# Git repo version

Tags: node.js, git

I compiled node.js from it's github repo. Running `$ node --version` outputs `v0.13.0-pre`. But where can I find this version information inside my cloned repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many projects you can call `git describe` to get current tag, which is used as version string.

But Node.js don't use this convention. You must call `tools/getnodeversion.py` script. It will compose current version string from lines of "src/node_version.h" file.

Comment: Perfect! This is the answering I was looking for!